Resizing img inside a div after onTouch without the image bouncing around inside the div
I have a div that holds 2 imgs (Pokemon) when I click on the img I enlarge it so it's apparent which Pokemon I'm switching to. But it jumps around / bounces inside the div making it look not appealing for the game. I use p5.js and have dynamically made the images with onTouch events to resize the image. One issue might be the fact that the pokemon images I use start as different sizes loaded in. Witch I reside the best I can to start around the same size. I'm hoping I can post pictures to show what's going on along side my code. Everything for the game is in 1 html file and 1 js file hopefully making it easy for someone to run and see the problem.
I've tried resizing I've tried setting max-widths + max-heights expecting this to solve the problem of it looking funky when I make the selected pokemon bigger

// Create Pokemon Container Div
 
      div_pkmnContainer = createDiv();
div_pkmnContainer.position
(width / 2 - 100, height / 2 + 600);  //h290
div_pkmnContainer.size(300,200);
div_pkmnContainer.style('background-color', 'lightblue');
div_pkmnContainer.style('border', 'dotted');
div_pkmnContainer.hide();
